# Update ActiveRecord object including association and get error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to update a record which includes a `has_many` association and wish to process any errors. Using `update_attributes` works great if there are no associations but if an association is not valid (violates a unique constraint, for example) then all I get is a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved` error, but nothing in the `@object.errors`.

Controller Code

```
respond_to do |format|
  begin
    if @calmapp_version.update_attributes(params[:calmapp_version])
      tflash('update', :success, {:model=>@@model, :count=>1})
      format.html { redirect_to( :action => "index")} 
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved => e
     flash[:error] = @calmapp_version.errors.full_messages
     format.html { render :action => "edit" }
  end
end
```

Models

```
    class CalmappVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :calmapp_versions_translation_languages, :dependent => :destroy
      ....
    end

    class CalmappVersionsTranslationLanguage < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :calmapp_version
      belongs_to :translation_language

      validates :translation_language_id, :uniqueness => {:scope=> :calmapp_version_id}
    end
```

Where is the violation of uniqueness message and how do I access it?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `update_attributes!`.  Notice the !.  This will produce an exception if a record isn't valid and give you more insight into what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the other question  `Where is the violation of uniqueness message and how do I access it?`

you can look here (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)  and include the message in the uniqueness hash  such as

```
validates :translation_language_id, :uniqueness => {:scope=> :calmapp_version_id, message => 'There Can Be Only 1'}
```